# How to avoid overwriting a file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a program that will take the answers of what the user inputted and put it in a text document in Python 2.7.  I have the problem of when running the program again, the text document is overwritten and the previous data was deleted. So I was wondering how to avoid this problem. If this was already answered, please link the article. Thanks a bunch in advance!

```
import time
import sys as LOL
print 'Welcome to the database, enter -1 to exit.'
time.sleep(1)
files = open('c:/writing.txt','w')
name = raw_input('Enter in your name... ')
if name == '-1':
    LOL.exit()
time.sleep(1)
if len(name)> 64 or len(name)< 1:
    print 'Please enter a name that is between 1 and 64 characters!!'
while len(name)>64 or len(name)<1:
    name = raw_input('Enter in your name... ')
    if name == '-1':
        LOL.exit()
    if len(name)> 64 or len(name)<1:
        print 'Please enter a name that is between 1 and 64 characters!!'
        time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(1)
age = int(raw_input('Enter in your age... '))
if age == -1:
    LOL.exit()
while age > 125 or age < 1:
    age = int(raw_input('Enter in your age... '))
    if name == '-1':
        LOL.exit()
    time.sleep(1)
    if age > 125 or age < 1:
        print 'Enter in a vaild age!'
newedit = name + ' is %s years old.' %age
files.write(newedit)
files.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you opened the file in `w` mode (write mode).  As you can read in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), doing so automatically truncates it:

> The most commonly-used values of mode are `'r'` for reading, `'w'` for
>   writing (**truncating the file if it already exists**), and `'a'` for
>   appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to
>   the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).

As the excerpt above says, you should use `a` mode to append text to a file without truncation:

```
files = open('c:/writing.txt','a')
```

Answer (score 4):

An append 'a' rather that write 'w' mode should probably do it so you use the line 
`f = open("text.txt", 'a')`.